# How can I check if my mouse x position is in my image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, mouse-position

I have an onmouseenter event, and in that I get an array of images via the jquery selector $('.imageTile').  In Chrome I was able to do this to get the index of the element I was really interested in:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.imageTile').length; i++)
{
   if(e.y >= $('.imageTile')[i].y && e.y <= $('.imageTile')[i].y + $('.imageTile')[i].height) {
       index = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

but in IE, this isn't working.  Is there some weird hack I need to use?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There's probably an easier way to do it. Are you trying to get the index of the image being hovered?

Comment: `$('.imageTile').on('hover', function() { console.log($(this).index(); });`

Comment: I'd like to get the X as some point too, because I'm looking to set an image next to the image I'm hovering over, and it would be nice to set the tops the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, but I haven't tested it.

```
var index = -1;
$(function(){
    $('.imageTile img').hover(function(){
        index = $('.imageTile').index($(this));
    },
    function(){ 
        index = -1; // reset index on mouseout
    });
});
```

You got to love jQuery, https://api.jquery.com/index/